# Subquery returned more than 1 value error after executing update query

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql-server 2012 and i have a strange problem in updating a table.

My select query returns tree rows and is like below:

```
select * from 
    TAble1 p join
    (select ProductId=max(ProductId) from Table2 s group by s.ProductId) pin on p.id=pin.ProductId
    where p.categoryid=238
```

and the returned row is:

[image]

Now, When i run this update query:

```
update TAble1 set sizing=0 from 
    TAble1 p join
    (select ProductId=max(ProductId) from TAble2 s group by s.ProductId) pin on p.id=pin.ProductId
    where p.categoryid=238
```

I got this error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Where is the problem in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem that generates an exception is somewhere else (inside of a trigger for example).

This line could be the reason why there is more than one row updated

```
(select ProductId=max(ProductId) from TAble2 s group by s.ProductId)
```

If you want to obtain max ProductID (a single value) - remove it from GROUP BY clause. Currently you are requesting server to return maximum from a single value - which is absurd. It simply returns a list of all ProductID values from Table2. Which is the same as

```
select distinct ProductID from Table2
```

Comment: it was a trigger. Thank you!

Comment: triggers runs after one row update or something else?

Comment: All updated rows are listed in INSERTED and DELETED temp tables accessible from the trigger

Answer (score 0):

This `select ProductId=max(ProductId) from Table2 s group by s.ProductId`
will give you DISTINCT ProductId's, but not `MAX`. And You dont have link with TAble1 In fact your query will update all `TAble1.sizing` column.
Try this:

```
UPDATE TAble1
SET sizing = 0
FROM TAble1 p 
JOIN
    (SELECT max(s.ProductId) AS ProductId 
    FROM TAble2) pin 
        ON p.id = pin.ProductId AND p.categoryid=238
WHERE p.categoryid = categoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better question is what isn't the problem in your query. In your SELECT what exactly are you supposed to be joining? And what index are you joining it to? You're using a GROUP BY but not including the GROUP BY as a column in your SELECT.  You don't need to alias the 'TAble2 s' in the subquery. TAble p doesn't have a categoryid column based on what you've shown.  You shouldn't need the FROM clause in the UPDATE query in most cases, especially since you're just setting a column to a static value.

But to answer your question: the subquery: "select ProductId=max(ProductId) from TAble2 s group by s.ProductId" returns all ProductId rows, so it fails when you're trying to join.

Since you're not using info from Table2 why not just simply update like this:

```
update TAble1 set sizing=0 where categoryid=238
```